# Org mode how to continue list on previous heading after subheading

Tags: org-mode

[image]

Please see in the image how I expect to put down the information in an org file. Sub-heading 1 has some list items which are collapsed, after which I would like to continue the list at the previous level.

I see how this can be hard to parse as I want it, since the underlying file is just plain text and org-indent-mode is trying to lay it out, but is there a way to capture lists as shown in the image? Can I earmark a particular list item to belong to a higher level heading?

After the state shown in the picture, if I expand and collapse sub-heading 1, 'Third thing' will become a list item under it.

Comment: Content after a subheading is not supported by org-mode syntax. There is no way to indicate a subheading has ended, and it is also very unintuitive to read. Use nested lists if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The feature that you’re looking for is only available for ordered lists.

> Ordered list items start with a numeral followed by either a period or a right parenthesis10, such as ‘1.’ or ‘1)’11 If you want a list to start with a different value—e.g., 20—start the text of the item with ‘[@20]’12. Those constructs can be used in any item of the list in order to enforce a particular numbering. ~ [org-mode manual - plain lists](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-Lists.html).

For example,

```
* Heading 1 @ level 0
  1. list item 1 @ level 1
  2. list item 2 @ level 1
** Sub-heading 1 @ level 1
  3. [@3] list item 3 @ level 1
```

However, if you do not want to use an ordered list then my recommendation is to convert each `headline` into a `plain list` instead.

For example,

```
- *Heading 1* @ level 0
  + list item 1 @ level 1
  + list item 2 @ level 1
    - *Sub-heading 1* @ level 2
  + list item 3 @ level 1
```